# Prime number using a pipe

Tags: pipe, c

I have a question about pipes in C. So I'm trying to read a number from the parent process until 0 and to print in the child process if it is prime. But the child process will print only the value of that number and the current result will be printed only after the next read. I can't figure out why this is happening. Also I've done a similar exercise before to print the parity on the same architecture and that worked fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        int p2c[2];
        int res = pipe(p2c);
        if(res == -1)
        {
                perror("pipe(p2c) error: ");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        int pid = fork();
        if(pid == -1){
                perror("fork() error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(pid == 0)
        {
                close(p2c[1]);
                while(1)
                {
                        int a;
                        read(p2c[0], &a, sizeof(int));
                        printf("[In CHILD] a: %d\n",a);
                        if(a==0)
                                break;
                        else{
                        int ok = 1;
                        if(a<2)
                        {
                                ok = 0;
                        }
                        for(int d=2;d*d<=a && ok == 1; d++)
                        {
                                if(a%d==0)
                                        ok=0;
                        }
                        if(ok == 1){
                                printf("Prime");}
                        else{
                                printf("Not prime");}
                        }

                }
                close(p2c[0]);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else{
        close(p2c[0]);
        while(1)
        {
                int a;
                printf("[In PARENT]: a");
                scanf("%d", &a);

                write(p2c[1], &a, sizeof(int));
                if(a==0)
                        break;
                sleep(3);
        }
        int status;
        wait(&status);

        printf("\n[In PARENT] Child has finished with exit status: %d\n", status);
        close(p2c[1]);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to move this question to StackOverflow as it has to do with programming and not Unix/Linux.

Comment: If the child is receiving the values correctly but not screening them for primes correctly, then the problem has nothing to do with pipe communication, and you should remove all of the pipe/fork code.